# OkHTTP3 Response Print Issue

Tags: java, json, okhttp

So I've recently tried to do some stuff using Java and I noticed a strange problem. So I have this bit of code here

```
Response response = client2.newCall(request).execute();

System.out.println(response.body().string());

JSONObject ir = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

System.out.println(ir);

Double low = ir.getDouble("CurrentLowestOfferPrice");

System.out.println("\nLOW = " + low);
```

The problem I had was that the first print statement actually messed with the assignment of the response object in the next line and I could not get the JSON values.

Can anyone explain why this happens?
(Picture below for clarification. Top is run using snippet of code above, bottom is removing the first print statement)

[image: Top being error, bottom being correct.]

Comment: surround with try, catch and add the trace here, please

Answer (score 0):

You can only read the body once.  Assign and reuse.

```
Response response = client2.newCall(request).execute();

try {
  String s = response.body().string();
  System.out.println(s);

  JSONObject ir = new JSONObject(s);

  System.out.println(ir);

  Double low = ir.getDouble("CurrentLowestOfferPrice");

  System.out.println("\nLOW = " + low);
} finally {
  response.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps a lot. :) Just a quick question, why does it only read the body once? Is it because it is synchronous and not asynchronous?

Comment: Because you are consuming a potentially large response from the network

Comment: Ahh cool, I'll keep a note of that in the future. Thanks Yuri ^-^